# Change style of the above cell

Tags: notebooks, formatting, cells, text

How can I change the style of a given cell,
by writing some code on the cell directly below the cell and executing it?

```
I want to change this cell (*the cell that I want to change cell-style*)

SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], Previous, Cell];
...
```

I know that the code probably start like this, but I can't go further.

If it is possible using
menu(mouse right click on the target cell..?) or
shortcuts(when cursor is on the target cell..?),
I also want to know it.

Comment: You don’t want to just use the menus?

Comment: It would be good or better if it is possible using menu also!

Comment: It is possible to use the menus: Format -> Style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we move the selection to the previous cell:

```
SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], Previous, Cell];
```

We now read the selected cell, change its style e.g. to "Section" and rewrite the changed cell:

```
NotebookWrite[cell = SelectedCells[][[1]], 
 ReplacePart[NotebookRead[cell], 2 -> "Section"]]
```

Finally we move the selection back to the original cell:

```
SelectionMove[cell, Next, Cell];
```

For convenience, here is everything together:

```
SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], Previous, Cell];
NotebookWrite[cell = SelectedCells[][[1]], 
 ReplacePart[NotebookRead[cell], 2 -> "Section"]]
SelectionMove[cell, Next, Cell]
```

;

Comment: Thank you, learned SelectedCells and NotebookWrite

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way :

Cell to be transformed :

```
I want to change this cell (*the cell that I want to change cell-style*)
```

Cell to transform the previous cell :

```
CurrentValue[PreviousCell[], StyleNames] = "Section"
```

After evaluation it gives :
[image]

`PreviousCell` is documented.
`CurrentValue[..., StyleNames]=...` is not, so far I know. The idea to use this syntax comes from the documentation of `Cells`, paragraph "Application", where there is this code :

```
     Scan[(CurrentValue[#, StyleNames] = "Subsection") &, 
 Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Section"]]
```